# Angular17 ngSrc optimezedImage

Tags: angular

I'm trying to do this at angular 17:

// typescript

```
get getWidth(): number {
    // this._el is an inject(ElementRef);
    const width = +this._el.nativeElement.querySelector(
      '[id="fs-img-container"]'
    ).clientWidth;

    return (80 / 100) * width - 1;
}
get getHeight(): number {
    const height = +this._el.nativeElement.querySelector(
      '[id="fs-img-container"]'
    ).clientHeight;

    return (80 / 100) * height - 1;
}
```

// html

```
<img
  ngSrc="assets/hero-illustration.svg"
  [width]="getWidth"
  [height]="getHeight"
/>
```

This works perfectly and the expected result is obtained, however in the console it shows the following error:
ERROR RuntimeError: NG02952: The NgOptimizedImage directive (activated on an  element with the `ngSrc="assets/hero-illustration.svg"`) has detected that `height` has an invalid value. To fix this, provide `height` as a number greater than 0.

Is there any way to suppress this error message or resolve the issue?

I try to get the image size of 80% of the parent div, since with the ngSrc directive it's not possible to pass a width and height in percentage, and this works, but with an console error.

Comment: you can default your properties and ensure the return value of your getters always returns 1 or greater

Answer (score 0):

The error message seems to indicates the value given by getHeight is negative but the behavior you expected is ok because this value change after your element is fully rendered so maybe try to figure out the value of height in your expression "(80 / 100) * height - 1" during the time. If you want to ride of this error, make a console.log(height) in your getHeight() to see the value during the time and make the return value never be negative.